# Win XP 64 bit and .NET 4.0 issue

Tags: wpf, wcf, windows-xp

I'm developing a WPF with WCF app on .NET 4.0, the machine in which is being developed is a Windows 7 64 bit SP1. The app has already been installed in several machines with different configurations (Win XP, Vista, 7, and even POS), summing up to a total of around 20 different machines.

Yesterday I went to install it on a new customer, and the app just crashed with no error message (probably due to my several try catches along the code). The only message that showed was something like: The App stopped working, Windows is trying to find a solution.

Tried different configurations and nothing, until I noticed that the client machine is a Win XP 64 bit, which I believe I've never came across until now.

I searched the web, and read somewhere that there was a compatibility issue with Win XP x64 and .NET 4.0. I don't know if this is the case.

Do I have to downgrade my app to .NET 3.5?? Or do I have to create a 64 version, or is it the client machine that has a problem?? I can't recreate the issue on my PS, even with Win XP installed on virtual machine, so I'm flying blind.

Comment: Asking for a 'fast solution' is really rude. After all, those answers you, do it for free

Comment: First off, are you compiling your code for "Any CPU"? Also, what is the exact version of Windows XP?

Comment: You really should be getting the underlying exception that is happening. Without it it is impossible to answer your question. If you can't reproduce the problem on a XP 64 bit in your lab, that's most likely not the problem.

Comment: Steve, the 'fast', although true, is merely ironic, since this is the forum where I get the fastest replies. And it's running on Any CPU, as for the try catch, I've been rewriting the code to show the error, but it just wouldn't be professional to go to the client with no solution... thanks

Comment: [Was the client OS SP3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww%28VS.100%29.aspx)? Also, is it possible to compile it against 3.5 (and thus use the 2.0 runtime) or does compilation fail? Could be an easy way to determine if its a .NET 4 on XP issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to install Windows Imaging Component, which is mentioned in .NET Framework download page,

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851

> Important: Make sure that your computer has the latest Windows service
>   pack and critical updates. To find security updates, visit Windows
>   Update. If you are installing on XP 64 bit or Windows 2003 you might
>   need to install the Windows Imaging Component. The Windows Imaging
>   Component 32 bit can be found here . The Windows Imaging Component 64
>   bit can be found here .

Anyway, you should debug the crash as @Daniel Hilgarth recommended, as that can tell if WIC is the culprit.

Comment: Sorry for not repling earlier. After a few dozen hours of try and fail, and google askint, I found that installing Windows Imaging Component solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: Nice find! Downloaded the mentioned 64-bit version and voila. It is strange, since I tried to install WIC from somewhere else and that did not help. Well, happy that it works now.